# SQL WHERE condition is not equal to?

Tags: mysql, sql, where-clause, negate

Is it possible to negate a where clause?

e.g.

```
DELETE * FROM table WHERE id != 2;
```

Comment: FYI, `id != NULL` does **not** work as you'd expect.

Answer (score 178, accepted):

You can do like this

```
DELETE FROM table WHERE id NOT IN ( 2 )
```

OR

```
DELETE FROM table WHERE id <>  2
```

As @Frank Schmitt noted, you might want to be careful about the NULL values too. If you want to delete everything which is not `2`(including the NULLs) then add `OR id IS NULL` to the WHERE clause.

Comment: I tried this command a couple of times.. but it didn't seem to work until I realized that DELETE in MySQL does not use the * ..

Comment: There you go, edited the answer to remove the * Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: Just a general comment for people who got here wondering why their `!= NULL` isn't working: "You cannot use arithmetic comparison operators such as =, <, or <> to test for NULL." ([from the MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/working-with-null.html)). So that means you **have to use** `IS NOT NULL`.

Comment: when using NOT IN () , i get ( 'SQL logic error near "WHERE": syntax error' )

Answer (score 32):

Your question was already answered by the other posters, I'd just like to point out that

```
 delete from table where id <> 2
```

(or variants thereof, not id = 2 etc) will not delete rows where id is NULL.

If you also want to delete rows with id = NULL:

```
delete from table where id <> 2 or id is NULL
```

Answer (score 14):

You could do the following:

```
DELETE * FROM table WHERE NOT(id = 2);
```

Comment: Works well if the value is not numeric WHERE NOT(id = 'two');

Answer (score 13):

```
delete from table where id <> 2
```

edit: to correct syntax for MySQL

Answer (score 9):

Use `<>` to negate the where clause.

Answer (score 7):

`WHERE id <> 2` should work fine...Is that what you are after?

Answer (score 7):

Look back to formal logic and algebra. An expression like

```
A & B & (D | E)
```

may be negated in a couple of ways:

- The obvious way:

  ```
  !( A & B & ( D | E ) )
  ```
- The above can also be restated, you just need to remember some properties of logical expressions:

  - `!( A & B )` is the equivalent of `(!A | !B)`.
  - `!( A | B )` is the equivalent of `(!A & !B)`.
  - `!( !A )` is the equivalent of (A).

  Distribute the NOT (!) across the entire expression to which it applies, inverting
    operators and eliminating double negatives as you go along:

  ```
      !A | !B | ( !D & !E )
  ```

So, in general, any where clause may be negated according to the above rules. The negation of this

```
select *
from foo
where      test-1
  and      test-2
  and (    test-3
        OR test-4
      )
```

is

```
select *
from foo
where NOT(          test-1
           and      test-2
           and (    test-3
                 OR test-4
               )
         )
```

or

```
select *
from foo
where        not test-1
  OR         not test-2
  OR   (     not test-3
         and not test-4
       )
```

Which is better? That's a very context-sensitive question. Only you can decide that.

Be aware, though, that the use of NOT can affect what the optimizer can or can't do. You might get a less than optimal query plan.

Answer (score 7):

Best solution is to use

```
DELETE FROM table WHERE id NOT IN ( 2 )
```

Answer (score 5):

Yes. If memory serves me, that should work.
Our you could use:

```
DELETE FROM table WHERE id <> 2
```

Answer (score 0):

I was just solving this problem. If you use <> or is not in on a variable, that is null, it will result in false. So instead of <> 1, you must check it like this:

```
 AND (isdelete is NULL or isdelete = 0)
```