# Select all rows but one

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am trying to show all user information held in a db.

```
SELECT * FROM member
```

However i do not want it to select the current user (find by personID)

Is there a way to say select all but not personID XXXX?

Thanks

Comment: Use the `WHERE` clause

Comment: But what would i put `SELECT * from MEMBER where personID not 'XXXX'`?

Comment: the `not` in SQL is `<>`

Comment: @fluminis: Or `!=` :-)

Comment: @user3092953 searching for "sql where not" brought as first link this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6156979/sql-where-condition-not-equal-to (possible duplicate but I already voted on off topic)

Comment: @DanieleBrugnara: Umm.. can we help you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `<>` or `!=` as an not equal to operator.

```
SELECT * FROM member WHERE personID <> 123;
SELECT * FROM member WHERE personID != 123;
```

If you want to exclude multiple IDs:

```
SELECT * FROM member WHERE personID NOT IN (1,2,3);
```

Comment: MySQL supports `!=` as well.

Comment: And PHP supports `<>`. 

http://us1.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/non-typed-operators.html

Comment: Thanks guys, learn something every day. Couldn't see any difference from the docs. Do they perform identically?

Comment: @SamSullivan: Yes, `<>` and `!=` are equivalent.